How to filter pandas dataframe for strings that contain all substrings in a given list
I'm trying to filter out rows of a dataframe where a column of strings under the name 'question' contains all the substrings in a given list. That is, if the given list of substrings is ['King', 'England'], then I need to retain all the rows in the dataframe where the string in the df.question contains both King and England.
This code executes without any problems and prints out a boolean value:
print(all([word in df.question[0] for word in ['King', 'England']]))

But this code results in the following error:
print(df[all([word in df.question for word in ['King', 'England']])])

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3805, in Index.get_loc(self, key)
   3804 try:
-> 3805     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3806 except KeyError as err:

File index.pyx:167, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File index.pyx:196, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas\\_libs\\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:7081, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

File pandas\\_libs\\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:7089, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: False

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 2
      1 print(all([word in df.question[0] for word in ['King', 'England']]))
----> 2 print(df[all([word in df.question for word in ['King', 'England']])])

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:4102, in DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
   4100 if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   4101     return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 4102 indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   4103 if is_integer(indexer):
   4104     indexer = [indexer]

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3812, in Index.get_loc(self, key)
   3807     if isinstance(casted_key, slice) or (
   3808         isinstance(casted_key, abc.Iterable)
   3809         and any(isinstance(x, slice) for x in casted_key)
   3810     ):
   3811         raise InvalidIndexError(key)
-> 3812     raise KeyError(key) from err
   3813 except TypeError:
   3814     # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3815     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3816     #  the TypeError.
   3817     self._check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: False

How do I filter rows in a Dataframe based on this condition?

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html to combine with AND: df[(df.str.contains('England')) & (df.str.contains('King'))]

You can use .str.contains to check each word and then np.all over axis=0 to combine all boolean values for each row:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "question": [
            "Who is the King of England?",
            "Where is England?",
            "England King",
            "King",
        ]
    }
)

df2 = df[
    np.all([df['question'].str.contains(word) for word in ["King", "England"]], axis=0)
]

print(df2)

Output:
                      question
0  Who is the King of England?
2                 England King


maybe df.extractall with a boolean could work.
as per the docs str.extracall as opposed to str.extract returns:

DataFrame A DataFrame with one row for each match, and one column for
each group. Its rows have a MultiIndex with first levels that come
from the subject Series. The last level is named ‘match’ and indexes
the matches in each item of the Series. Any capture group names in
regular expression pat will be used for column names; otherwise
capture group numbers will be used.

pat = '(' + '|'.join(['King','England']) + ')'
#'(King|England)'
out = df[df['question'].str.extractall(pat).groupby(level=0).size() > 1]

print(out)

                      question
0  Who is the King of England?
2                 England King
 

further reading:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html

This would match strings like King King and England England.

@Dogbert easily fixable by using regex or expanding the rules after str.extractall

What do you mean by "expanding the rules"?
